# setValue in dropdown not updating value variable in Text element react native

Tags: react-native

I've got a dropdown, and setValue to setValue of value to the selection of the dropdown. I've also got a text element that should display the value whenever the dropdown is changed, but when I change the dropdown it doesn't update the Text and it stays blank? This is the dropdown I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-element-dropdown

```
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<ProductType[] | []>([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(' ');
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

 
  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.32:3000/api/products');
      setProducts(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      alert('no');
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <AppBar
        title="App"
        trailing={props => (
          <Button
            variant="text"
            title="ADD"
            compact
            //onPress={getProducts}
            style={{marginEnd: 4}}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />

      <Dropdown
        style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && {borderColor: 'blue'}]}
        data={products}
        search
        maxHeight={300}
        labelField="product"
        valueField="aisle"
        placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select item' : '...'}
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        value={value}
        onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
        onChange={item => {
          setValue(item.value);
          setIsFocus(false);
        }}
      />
      <TextInput label="quantity" variant="standard" />
      <Text>value: {value}</Text>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  dropdown: {
    height: 50,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `onChange` function is being fired and the value `setValue` is receiving is the problem, not the `Dropdown` component.

I've recreated your code (removed the AppBar for simplicity) and replaced your api with [dummyjson](https://dummyjson.com/) and [this code](https://snack.expo.dev/h6BqHdcGb) worked:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(' ');
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

 
  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://dummyjson.com/products');
      setProducts(response.data.products);
    } catch (error) {
      // handle error
      alert('Oh no','...');
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown
        style={[styles.dropdown, isFocus && {borderColor: 'blue'}]}
        data={products}
        search
        maxHeight={300}
        labelField="title"
        valueField="title"
        placeholder={!isFocus ? 'Select item' : '...'}
        searchPlaceholder="Search..."
        value={value}
        onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
        onChange={item => {
          setValue(item.title);
          setIsFocus(false);
        }}
      />
      <TextInput label="quantity" variant="standard" />
      <Text>value: {value}</Text>
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I see that `aisle` is the value you gave to the `valueField`. Did you mean to do `setValue(item.aisle)` and not `setValue(item.value)`?

If `item.value` is what you want then verify that it isnt an empty string. Log it in your `onChange` function.